# Activity with action bar but without title?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

How to achieve this? It seems very simple, but actually it's not easy to do it in acceptable way. I tried this:

1) in AndroidManifest I set activity theme to Theme.NoTitleBar. However, in my Activity then getActionBar() method returns null => UNUSABLE

2) I hide title programatically in my activity by calling:

```
actionbar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
actionbar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
```

and it helped, but there's a little delay, so I can see title bar maybe quarter of second after activity launch, then it disappears. It looks really lame.

Are there other options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply a custom theme to your Activity, something like:

```
<style name="TestTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/TestActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="TestActionBar" parent="android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/actionbar_background</item>
    <item name="android:displayOptions"></item>
</style>
```

This will show the action bar with the logo, but no title.

Comment: well, I don't want to show logo or title - just and only action bar (for example with tabs, or so) without anything other

Comment: @qkx Remove the useLogo option then

Comment: I removed "useLogo" and also android:background as I don't want to have specific bacground. However, still see the title...

Comment: Are you sure you're applying the theme to your Activity?

Comment: sorry, I wasn't clear - now the title is gone, but still can see some row above in the activity - it's the row where is usually icon+title, now there's only icon - but still I need the row to be "gone" or hidden...If you understand me

Comment: Uh, that row is the action bar. Are you trying to make your Activity full screen?

Comment: no...actually action bar has always 2 rows - first is like info row (title + icon) and second is actually bar with controlls (actions, tabs, etc). However when I used this: 

<item name="android:displayOptions"></item>

it is now perfect - exactly what I wanted :) Please edit your answer  so I will accept it.

Comment: @qkx Ah okay. I misunderstood you earlier. My mistake. I've edited my answer.

Comment: thanks for helping ;) I've still some problems with styling, for me it's a little bit unintutive...I never understanded for example why it doesn't work when I don't set a parent to TestTheme (leave it empty) when other activity styles works even without specifying parent. Or why it looks exactly same, when I set parrent to Widget.DeviceDefault and Theme.DeviceDefault. What's the difference...and many, many issues with styling are mystery for me.

Answer (score -1):

Have u try bellow code :-

```
getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
getActionBar().hide();
setContentView(R.layout.ur activityxml);
```

or also try below one

```
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);  

    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,   
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);  

    setContentView(R.layout.activityxml);
```

Comment: The OP does not want to hide the actionbar.