# How can I get Address Bar to be screened in my Android app?

Tags: android, android-webview, android-fullscreen, android-titlebar

I made a simple Web View in Eclipse. It's my first app. I can get my first app page without any title bar or Address bar. But when I click any button into next app page, the Address Bar appears. I want all app pages without Address Bar or Title bar. Please show me the way to all app pages with full screen. Any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: I would use a custom theme in the activities. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14854309/activity-with-action-bar-but-without-title maybe this will help you. Try to search for your problem first.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2378800/clicking-urls-opens-default-browser/2379054, as you are seeing the user's default browser. There is no address bar in a `WebView`, unless you put one there yourself.

Comment: When I apply CommonsWare's solution, "HelloWebViewClient" is red-underlined. It says " HelloWebViewClient is never used locally".  What shall I do for that?

Comment: @LynnCrumbling: see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231504/how-do-i-opt-out-of-privileges

Comment: @민현식: I would suggest that you either edit your question to provide your code, or open a fresh Stack Overflow question where you provide your code. Nobody can really help you with this message without the code that is generating the message.

Comment: Do I have to provide my code?  Of course,I think I have to. But I am new here. When I intend to provide my code, small red box says there is something wrong.

Comment: Would you mind showing me the way to post my code? Is there any tutorial about how to post one's code?

Comment: @민현식 You can edit your question and add the code. Click the "edit" link, just below the question.